# Breadcrumbs css issue in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I am facing issue in breadcrumbs. We have attrbute for menu items like

```
expanded?: boolean;
disabled?: boolean;
visible?: boolean; 
badgeStyleClass?: string;
style?:any;
styleClass?:string;
```

But nothing is working above the attr in primeng. How to set class for style

and above the condition is not working.Anyone help me.

Comment: can you explain a little more which problem do you have?

Comment: These attr are not working :    expanded: true,
        disabled: true,
        visible: true,  
        badgeStyleClass: 'ui-state-active',
        style:'ui-state-active',
        styleClass:'ui-state-active',

Comment: where are you setting them?

Comment: Can you check thisone:https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/common/menuitem.ts

Answer (score 0):

you might have missed to add font awesome url `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

I have updated the code. please check, is this what you need?
 `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-routing-bread-crumbs-mfr1ao?embed=1&file=src/index.html`

Comment: Not use..Can you understand my questions?

Comment: Did't understand your problem then

Comment: I have checked it and already implemented but I did't get your problem? What breadcrumb CSS issue are you facing?

Comment: Can you apply this condition:  label: "Testing", 
        url: "test",
        routerLink: 'c1', 
        expanded: true,
        disabled: true,
        visible: true,  
        badgeStyleClass: 'ui-state-active',
        style:'ui-state-active',
        styleClass:'ui-state-active',
        title: 'ui-state-active',
        id: 'ui-state-active',
        automationId: 'ui-state-active'

Comment: It seems you are using the wrong constant file. `https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/common/menuitem.ts` link is for menu editing and `BreadCrumb` does not support all of them

Comment: Only these are supported `model, home, style, styleClass` You can style them by external styling Or use `<p-breadcrumb [model]="items" styleClass="myclass" [home]="home"></p-breadcrumb>`